# How do I identify my closet system (or do I even need to)?

Tags: closet

In October I moved into a condo. All the bedrooms had built-in closet systems, but I don't know what brand/vendor. Why does it matter? I have a shelf or two with heavy things, and the shelf rocks back and forth when I move the heavy items. I want to get the thingie (not a technical term) that you put in the hole above the shelf to stabilize it, and I figured the spacing and hole size might vary depending on vendor.

So, is there any way at all to figure out who makes my closet? If not, do I even need to, or should I just take a measurement of the spacing and go to a store and ask for the shelf stabilizer thingie (any ideas what they're called?)?

The shelf when it's sitting normally:

[image]

When I put an unbalanced weight on it, this happens:

[image]

The shelf rests on shelf pins but there's nothing on the top side to prevent the shelf from flipping if the weight is unbalanced.

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't worry about what kind of closet "system". Just find a reasonable part to fix it. Can you post a picture of the problem shelf?

Comment: Welcome @Matt.  Please post a picture, it's impossible to give you a correct answer without one.   You didn't mention if this is a white "wire shelf" system, a melamine-chipboard shelf, or something else.

Comment: do you mean [shelf pins](https://www.richelieu.com/us/en/category/furniture-equipment/furniture-shelf-pins/metal-shelf-pin/1051209?sort=&nbPerPage=48) or [brackets](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Wall-Shelf-Brackets-Stainless-Steel-Triangle-Storage-Rack-Holder-Hardware-Kitchen-Organizer-Storage-Rack-Book-Shelf/32819360281.html)?

Comment: Updated the question, the shelf is on pins but there's nothing on the top of the shelf to keep it from flipping. I've seen x-shaped things on other shelves I've had, but don't k ow what they're called.

Answer (score 1):

search for "locking shelf pin" and you will get what you need.

[image]

They have a clip that holds the shelf board from tipping.

Most shelf pins are made for a 1/4 inch hole, but  not all. Take one of your pins to the home improvement center and compare it to the 1/4" ones there to make sure of its size.

Comment: I agree if the shelf is not two long the retainer type do work well, the most important part they (all 4 pins) need to be the same type having some round and some flattened will cause tipping +.

Comment: Picked up a few of these at a hardware store, the guy said they'd fit...and they don't. I think the shelf was too thick even if the pins had fit in the holes. This is why I was trying to identify the source of the closet. :). I'll find a better store to go to.

Comment: Not going to work. I got the right size, but the shelf is a tight fit, and with these locking shelf pins it just won't fit any more.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical boards might be installed wrong, with the two rows of pins closer to the back than to the front. My similar closet has pins closer to the front, which avoids forward tipping. Quite a job to deconstruct and put back together properly.